# Create Class or Function for Use proxy

Tags: python, mongodb, proxy

I want to use proxy settings for specific request not for all my script.
I have actually :

```
import whois
from pymongo import MongoClient
import socks
import socket



socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, "IP", 13012)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket


client = MongoClient()
db = client.pro
collection = db.domain
find_document = collection.find({"Field":"ERROR"},{'domain': 1, '_id':0})

domaine = d['domain']
print(domaine)
w = whois.whois(domaine) # I want to use proxy for this request
date = w.expiration_date
print date
collection.update({"domain": domaine}, {"$set": {"expire": date}})
```

But after that, impossible to connect into my mongodb on localhost.
My question is how can i use proxy for only specific request ?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Even if i set MongoClient() with Localhost, i have an error !! (Bad Gateway)

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer by myself, and i share it for you:

```
import socks

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, 'YOUR_IP', 8080)
socks.wrapmodule(whois) # Here is Whois Module force to use proxy
```